Embedded messaging deployment snippet to load as a portal User
I have explored the Embedded Messaging deployment and so far what I understood is what I am looking for is not possible to achieve but need help  if there is any workaround to achieve following or if there is really a out-of-the-box way to tackle it

Salesforce does provide the Code snippet which we can use on external site to load chat/messaging widget.
But is there any way to load that chat/messaging widget as one particular user? (In short like in Apex, we have RunAs feature where on can load script as particular user, looking similar way) basically the JS script for Chat Widget, is there any way we can mention ed in that that load this script as one of the Community User?

